# loadbalancing with difference nginx location context and backend server context

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, reverse-proxy

I used nginx and upstream module for load balancing with the following config

```
upstream lb {
  server 127.0.0.1:8080;
  server 127.0.0.1:8081;
 }
 server {
  listen 88;
  server_name localhost;

  location /cas/ {
    proxy_pass              http://lb;
    proxy_redirect          off;
    proxy_connect_timeout   2;
    proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }
}
```

the problem is the "location /context/" have to match to the context of backend server so when i request localhost/context/index.html then nginx routes it to 127.0.0.1:8080/context/index.html or 127.0.0.1:8080/context/index.html.

Is it possible to have difference backend context and nginx location for example with "location /" nginx will routes the request to 127.0.0.1:8080/context/index.html or 127.0.0.1:8080/context/index.html

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple location statements each with it's own upstream

```
location /cas/ {
  proxy_pass              http://lb; 
  }

location /web/ {
    proxy_pass              http://2b;    
  }

location /mail/ {
    proxy_pass              http://3b;    
  }
```

You can also use if statements that checks the $request_uri variable and uses that to decide what upstream to pass the request to.

```
if ($request_uri ~* "^/(.+?)/context")
{
  proxy_pass   http://domain.com$request_uri;
  break;
}
```

Comment: actually it's a bad idea to put proxy_pass inside if {}